# Function to count MySQL rows using WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, function

am making function to count rows using "WHERE", but i get a mysql error

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\AppServ\www\test\test\index.php on line 9
Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'

here is my function

```
    function CountRows($table, $field = NULL, $value = NULL){
        mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
        if($field != NULL && $value != NULL){
            return mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$table."` WHERE `".$field."` = `".$value."`"))or die(mysql_error());
        }else{
            return mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$table."`"));   
        }
    }
```

i've created this function to simplify counting rows mysql rows for banned members, inactive members etc, since all will be using WHERE

all help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your full query, please?  Also, since you're already using double quotes, do yourself a favor and move your variables inside them (or use single quotes and keep your variables where they are).

Comment: You'll need to show us the actual query that's causing the error. Also, you shouldn't encircle values in backticks `, but rather just single quotes '.

Comment: Can you print out the actual query sent in your mysql_query? The "ON clause" error seems weird

Comment: single quotes wont work, since am using Constants for tables names

Comment: The error is outside the code you posted... I'm guessing that `$table` is more than just a table name and includes some `JOIN`s that are erroring, as your query above doesn't use any `JOIN`s or an `ON` clause. Also, if you just want a count, you should `SELECT COUNT(*)` and read the returned column, rather than selecting all rows and reading the row count.

Comment: Problem solved guys, thanks it was because of using ` before and after table, fields names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not connect to database each time you need to do a query.. Just keep a persistent connection or ideally use PDO.
2. Value should be enclosed with simple single quotes. This is probably what is getting you an error, as anything enclosed in backticks kind of quotes is considered a database/table/field name.
3. Use COUNT(*), it does not fetch all the database rows.
4. If value is possibly supplied by user, make sure that it is safe by escaping it with mysql_real_escape_string if not using PDO.

Without using PDO code would be:

```
mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

function CountRows($table, $field = NULL, $value = NULL){

    if ($field != NULL && $value != NULL) {
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM `".$table."` 
                  WHERE `".$field."` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$table."`";   
    }

    $count = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    return $count[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the function was kinda sick lol, i fix issue i get another, but i've used yours and it works great, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Backticks (`) are for enclosing table and column names.  Don't wrap `$value` in them, just use single-quotes (').

Also, there's no reason you need to pull the full data set from the DB and count the rows in it.  Just query for the count:

```
    if($field != NULL && $value != NULL){
        $cnt = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `".$table."` WHERE `".$field."` = '".$value."'"))or die(mysql_error());
    }else{
        $cnt = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `".$table."`"));   
    }
    return $cnt['cnt'];
```

Comment: true, everything worked great since i removed ` from tables, columns, values
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally:

1. Do not connect/select database in the function. This should be done **one time** at the beginning of every page, no more (unless multiple connections are desired).
2. Do not `SELECT *` just so you can calculate the number of rows. Use MySQL's **[COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)** function instead.

   ```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(0) AS numRows FROM aTable");
   $numRows = mysql_result($result, 0, 'numRows');
   ```
3. Do NOT use your function with user input without taking appropriate actions to secure yourself against SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks all, problem solved after fixing the following
1-Removed ` before and after tables, fields names
2-Instead of mysql_num_rows, used COUNT(*)
Thanks all for help :)

Comment: i'll try to improve the function using your tips, Thanks